# android how to write Bluetooth Low energy device access

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have no idea about the android development, but in iOS we have a framework called CoreBluetooth for Bluetooth Low energy device connectivity.

Do we have the library in android to access BLE?.

Comment: Android devs changed to broadcom from bluez, so the open source project you found is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Android natively support BLE as of now. Some motorola devices said to have BLE hardware, but I don't think there is nothing at API level for us to work with.

Lot of people complaining about this in [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33371) thread. You can join too. The earliest you can persuade Google, the better.

Comment: @Whoami good find.. But I stand by what I said in the answer that Android doesn't **natively** support BLE.. I never considered 3rd party, Open source libraries. Regarding the library itself, I never used it, so I can't comment on it..

Answer (score 0):

Htc now uses broadcom api on top of bluez but named htc instead of broadcom and with a few changes to types.

Samsung got a secret one  but with bugs.

Google said in December and again this year that BLE will be next big feature. No releasedate though. Maybe Android 5?

Google are a few year too late.

Answer (score 0):

Google has announced plans for official Bluetooth LE support in API level 18. See here: http://www.theverge.com/2013/5/15/4334882/google-adopts-bluetooth-smart-hints-android-update-within-two-months

Currently, HTC offers an API (which, is of course, for HTC devices):

http://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/partner-apis/bluetooth-low-energy/

and as others have hinted, Samsung must have a secret one, as several bluetooth LE devices are working with samsung devices.

Answer (score 0):

Yea Google has finally announced something related to BLE. Check out this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html  .